# How to access a property from inside a function?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a JavaScript object literal used by KnockoutJs and from inside a function I cannot get to a property I need.

Is there a way to get there without changing the literal to something like this:

```
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;

    function remove(item) {
        self.myArray.remove(item)
    };
}
```

This is my current JavaScript:

```
var vm = {
    myArray: ko.observableArray([]),

    remove: function (item) {
        //debugger; Cant get to myArray
        //this is the item of the array
        myArray.remove(item);
    } // .bind(this)  doesn't work
}
```

and HTML:

```
 <!-- ko foreach: myArray-->
<button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.remove, uniqueName: true" >Remove</button>
  ...
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: `this` depends on how that function gets called. If you call the function like `vm.remove()` then `this` inside `remove` would be `vm`. Not familiar with Knockout but have you tried simply using `this.myArray.remove(item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways to solve this ( I personally prefer the first )

Bind the function when you declare remove

```
var vm = {
    myArray: ko.observableArray();
}
vm.remove = function(item) {
    this.myArray.remove(item);
}.bind(vm);

<button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">
```

Or bind the function on the data-bind expression

```
var vm = {
    myArray: ko.observableArray(),
    remove = function(item) {
        this.myArray.remove(item);
    }
}

<button data-bind="click: $parent.remove.bind($parent)">
```

Comment: doh, how obvious. lol.  thanks, went with the first one also.

Comment: Just for completeness... event bindings will have the "this" scope set to the current object ( $data ).  Because you're in a foreach binding that will be the current item in the observableArray

Answer (score 0):

When using the object literal syntax, you can just use the variable that's storing the object.

```
var vm = {
    myArray: ko.observableArray([]),

    remove: function (item) {
        vm.myArray.remove(item);
    }
}
```